# How to modify a cell value based on a change of value in a cell next to it

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to place a certain value into a cell, based on whether the value of a cell next to it has been edited. For example, if the value of any cell in column E has been edited by a user, a number must appear in the cell next to it in column F. Is there a simple way to do it in VBA?

Comment: Yes, take a look at the [`Worksheet.Change`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheet.change) event.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a really small example of how to do this.

First go into your VBE and double click the worksheet where this "Change" event is going to happen. We want to put this code specifically in that sheet.

Next you can paste this in:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    'Test to see if the thing that changed was in range E:E
    'Target variable will hold the range that experienced the change
    If Not Intersect(Range("E:E"), Target) Is Nothing Then

        'Declare a variable to hold a single cell that was changed
        Dim changedCell As Range

        'Loop through all the cells that were changed in column E
        'generally just one is changed, but it could be multiple
        For Each changedCell In Intersect(Range("E:E"), Target).Cells
            'Now we will increment the number that is in column F next to the cell that changed
            changedCell.Offset(0, 1).Value = changedCell.Offset(0, 1).Value + 1
        Next changedCell
    End If
End Sub
```

This subroutine is a special one. It's called `Worksheet_Change()` and it has one paramter called "Target". This will fire automatically every time anything changes in this tab/worksheet. `Target` will hold the range of cells that experienced the change.

This code tests to see if the range that was changed was in Column `E` and if so it goes through each cell that was changed (you can change multiple cells at a time with a copy/paste) and it simply increments a counter in column F next to each cell.

Comment: It works perfectly, a I updated it so that it doesnt lock up in an infinite loop myself. Thank you very much.